# Relation between the weak* topology and a metric topology on a separable normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb{K}$ -linear space and let $B^{\ast}=\{ f\in X^\ast ,||f||\leq 1$ },then $B^\ast$ is metrisable $\iff$ $X$ is separable. The corresponding metric is defined by $$d(f,g)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^n ||x_n||}|f(x_n)-g(x_n)|$$ Now this metric also induces a topology(say $T_d$) on $X^\ast$ .What is the relation between the weak* topology on $X^\ast$ and$(X^\ast,T_d)$?

Comment: sorry,it should be X*

Comment: The formula you give need not converge for arbitary $f,g$; the scaling factors works for $B^\ast$, not for $X^\ast$; so how are you solving that ?